# Why would this method need to be recursive?

Tags: c#, algorithm

On a whim, I've decided to go back and seek certification, starting with 98-361, Fundamentals of Software Development. (I'm doing this more for myself than anything else. I want to fill in gaps in my knowledge.)

In the very early course of the book, they present this interesting scenario in the Proficient Assessment section:

> You are developing a library of utility functions for your
>   application. You need to write a method that takes an integer and
>   counts the number of significant digits in it. You need to create **a recursive program**
>   to solve this problem. How would you write such a
>   program?

I find myself gaping at this scenario in befuddlement. If I understand "significant digits" correctly, there's no need whatsoever for a function that counts an integer's significant digits to be recursive. And, any architect who insisted that it be recursive should have his head examined.

Or am I not getting it? Did I completely miss something here? From what I understand, the significant digits are the digits of a number, starting from the left, and proceeding right, excluding any leading zeroes.

Under what conditions would this need to be recursive? (The whole point of this exercise for me is to learn new things. Someone throw me a bone.)

EDIT: I don't want an answer to the problem question. I can figure that out on my own. It just seems to me that this "problem" could be solved far more easily with a simple foreach loop over the characters in a string.

**Final Edit**

Given the sage advice of the awesome posters below, this was the simple solution I came up with to solve the problem. (Despite what misgivings I may have.)

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var values = new[] { 5, 15, 150, 250, 2500, 25051, 255500005, -10, -1005 };
        foreach (var value in values)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Signficiant digits for {0} is {1}.", value, SignificantDigits(value));
        }
    }

    public static int SignificantDigits(int n)
    {
        if (n == 0)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        return 1 + SignificantDigits((int)(n / 10));
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't NEED to be recursive. It's simply that the question is asking you to write a recursive implementation, presumably to test your understanding of how a recursive function works..

Comment: They probably just want to assess that you actually can write a recursive method and just use this as an example problem - there is no need to use recursion for this problem at all "in the real world".

Comment: I think the fact that you ask this question means you've mastered this exercise.

Comment: @Mike Hofer: "far more easily with a simple foreach loop" -- but not every language has a for loop, or at least not one that's natural.  Check out Haskell, for example.

Comment: @DSM: Noted, but this book is specifically targeted at C# developers. (Probably should have noted that in the question.)

Comment: Been programming like 20 years (half of it fulltime), never needed a certification in fundamentals of software development. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @Alex: As have I. This isn't going on my resume. It's a personal exercise, because I know there are gaps in my knowledge, and a structured approach to learning is likely the best way to fill them. :)

Comment: I kind of thought that software engineering was primarily an empirical, practice-driven thing. I don't mean to diminish all the good stuff that CS brings us, but in the end, it's something you do every day, not something you read about and answer multiple-choice tests and the like.

Comment: @Alex: Perhaps I haven't been clear. What are the differences between a dictionary and a hashtable? Why might I use one or the other? I customarily just choose a dictionary because I'm comfortable with it. The point of this exercise is to make myself go through the material in a structured fashion so that I will evaluate *the options available to me that I've never considered or wasn't aware of before*, broadening my toolset. It's not about multiple choice questions. It's about improving myself.

Comment: I see. In this case, it wouldn't hurt to get a popular book on algorithms and read it or just study/refresh the algorithms using Wikipedia (you can look up the algorithm names in the book's table of contents).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no *need* for such an algorithm to be recursive. But the intent here is not to write real-world code, it's to ensure *you* understand recursion.

Since you stated you weren't after code, I'll be careful here, but I need to provide *something* to compare the complexity of the solutions, so I'll use pseudo-code. A recursive solution may be something like:

```
def sigDigits (n):
    # Handle negative numbers.

    if n < 0:
        return sigDigits (-n)

    # 0..9 is one significant digit.

    if n < 10:
        return 1

    # Otherwise it's one plus the count in n/10 (truncated).

    return 1 + sigDigits (n / 10)
```

And you're right, it equally doable as iteration.

```
def sigDigits (n):
    # Handle negative numbers.

    if n < 0:
        n = -n

    # All numbers have at least one significant digit.

    digits = 1

    # Then we add one and divide by ten (truncated), until we get low enough.

    while n > 9:
        n = n / 10
        digits = digits + 1

    return digits
```

There are some (usually of a mathematical bent, and including myself) that consider recursive algorithms much more elegant where they're suitable (such as where the "solution search space" reduces very quickly so as to not blow out your stack).

I question the suitability in this *particular* case since the iterative solution is not too complex, but the questioner had to provide *some* problem and this one is relatively easy to solve.

And, as per your edit:

> ... could be solved far more easily with a simple foreach loop over the characters in a string

You don't *have* a string, you have an integer. I don't doubt that you could turn that *into* a string and then count characters but that seems a roundabout way of doing it.

Comment: I agree in the main with your assessment. As for my edit, well, one could argue that we *started* with an integer, and then took the most direct route to solving the problem. I'm a big fan of "Simplest solution that solves the problem correctly", and all that. It just seems to me that, in this particular case, recursion is a massive amount of overkill for the problem at hand. I use recursion quite a bit, actually, and this strikes me as a scenario where it is clearly not needed.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't ***need*** to be recursive. It's simply that the question is asking you to write a recursive implementation, presumably to test your understanding of how a recursive function works.

Answer (score 1):

That seems like a pretty forced example. The problem can be solved with an simpler iterative algorithm.

A lot of teaching resources really struggle to provide useful examples of when to use recursion. Technically you never *need* to use it, but for a large class of (mostly algorithmic) problems, it can really simplify things.

For example, consider any operation on a [binary tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree). Because the physical structure of a binary tree is recursive, the algorithms that operate on it are also naturally recursive. You can also write imperative algorithms to operate on binary trees, but the recursive ones are simpler to write and understand.